# How do you set up external Javascript code to be configurable?

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript code in an external file, and It's going to be for people to use on their own sites... so I want some way for them to be able to pass in multiple options... how would I do this?

Sorry, more information:

I would give them html + script + css to load:

```
    <div class="mywidget"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

And in the script (some of the code):

```
            var App = {

            init: function(){

                /* ----------------------------
                    On initialization....
                ---------------------------- */

                    App.doStuff(), App.doMoreStuff();

                },
                doStuff: function(){
                  alert('hi');
                }
            }
```

So I basically want them to be able to customize how my app works... so let's say I want them to customize the alert, or any other amount of things.

Comment: This is very vague. Is it a function those people are supposed to call? You could just have it accept an configuration object.

Comment: Yeah, please add detail -- "external file" ... external to what? Do you mean this is 'external' as opposed to inline? Is this executing in the context of a web application? Are you emailing the javascript to people so they can inject it into pages they are viewing? What do you mean by configurable? Pass in what kind of options? Sounds like you might be distributing a script which depends on a configuration file which provides parameters (or options) to the script. We can't help if we don't know where to start...

Comment: As it stands the solution is very straight-forward: use arguments. If you code `doStuff: function(text) { alert(text); }` then anyone can call `doStuff('foo');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard solution (used for example by jQuery), is to receive as argument in your function (or configuration function) only one argument, handled as a map :

```
   func veryFreeFunction(opts) {
      opts = opts || {}; 
      var a = opts.a || "default_a";
      var b = opts.b || "default_b";
      ...
   }
```

In this case, the user may call `veryFreeFunction();` or `veryFreeFunction({b:"test"});`. He will pass only the parameters he needs.

Comment: You came the closest to what I was looking for... I went with something a little different though.

Answer (score 2):

Do it the same way jQuery does. Have a parameter for an options object, then default the options if they aren't passed:

```
var yourFunc = function (options) {
    options = $.extend({
        prop1: 'default1',
        prop2: 'default2'
    }, options || {});

    // do stuff with options
};
```

If you don't use jQuery, you can easily stub `$.extend` by looping over the properties and replacing them if they're undefined.

Comment: jQuery just does things in the most awesome way possible, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the standard on this type of thing is to pass a JSON object into your library's static functions or object constructor, then merge the input parameter with your library's default parameter.

For example:

```
// Your library
function myLibObj(options){
    var default_options = {
         opt_1: "abc",
         opt_2: "def"
    };

    // Merge options
    $.extend(default_options, options);
}

var newObj = new myLibObj({opt_1: "ghi"});
// Now in this newObj, the options will look like {opt_1: "ghi", opt_2: "def"}
```

Comment: A "JSON object" ? JSON is a serialization norm. A JSON object would be a string.

Comment: Hmm... think he meant a "javascript object" ... saying JSON in javascript is a bit redundant unless you're actually parsing a JSON string and creating a JSO with it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is for the external file to look for a configuration block that's in the script tag itself:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js">
    var mySettings = {
            instanceName: 'homepage',
            cfg: {
                containerId: 'homepage-slide',
                columnsCount: 6,
                placeholder: true,
            }
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Note that you would have to parse the code yourself; the code is not run in case of an `src` attribute.

Comment: I think he means that if the <script> tag has a src element, the javascript inside the <script> tag will not be parsed and executed by default.

Comment: I'm basically saying this won't work unless you fetch the code inside and `eval` it.